# strange malloc behavior in C

Tags: c, malloc, int, short

I am trying to create a matrix with dynamic proportions and to initialize it
here is the code I am using to allocate memory and initialization:

```
int **matrix;
//mem allocation
matrix=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int*)*mat_w);
for (i=0;i<mat_w;i++)
    matrix[i]=(int)malloc(sizeof(int)*mat_h);
//init
for (i=0;i<mat_w;i++)
    for (j=0;j<mat_h;j++)
        matrix[i][j]=0;
```

This , works fine , question is , if I try to create a matrix of type short - I get a segmentation error on the init first pass.

Is this a C language issue or am I doing something wrong?

Code for matrix of type `short`:

```
short **matrix;
//mem allocation
matrix=(short*)malloc(sizeof(short*)*mat_w);
for (i=0;i<mat_w;i++)
    matrix[i]=(short)malloc(sizeof(short)*mat_h);
//init
for (i=0;i<mat_w;i++)
    for (j=0;j<mat_h;j++)
        matrix[i][j]=0;
```

P.S.: I dropped safety checks , index variables and boundary declarations for clarity of code.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Are you really casting the return value from `malloc` to integer types (rather than pointers) in your code? Also, indent code with 4 spaces to format it as code.

Comment: Don't you want matrix=(int*) or =(short*) ?

Comment: Ah, I see what happened. The formatter ate the extra * characters.

Comment: What happens in the loop? The problem may the initialization rather than the allocation.

Comment: Please post a minimal compilable code. It helps us to help you. Cheers!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your casts for the return value of `malloc()` are invalid. They should be `int**` and `int*` in the first case, and `short**` and `short*` in the second.

When you cast the return value of `malloc()` to `short`, a pointer returned gets truncated to fit in `short` value, and then gets assigned to a `short*` pointer, yielding a pointer value pointing to an invalid memory location. Therefore you get a segmentation fault trying to access it.

With `int`, you are getting lucky, since on your platform most probably `sizeof(int)==sizeof(int*)`, so that a pointer returned by `malloc()` casted to `int` is not truncated and it all silently works. It would most probably crash in a similar fashion on a 64-bit platform.

Should be:

```
short **matrix;
matrix=(short**)malloc(sizeof(short*)*mat_w);
for (i=0;i<mat_w;i++)
    matrix[i]=(short*)malloc(sizeof(short)*mat_h); 
for (i=0;i<mat_w;i++)
    for (j=0;j<mat_h;j++)
        matrix[i][j]=0;
```

If your code is pure C (not C++), you can omit the casts, as in C casting from `void*` to any other pointer type is valid.

```
short **matrix;
matrix = malloc(sizeof(short*)*mat_w);
for (i=0;i<mat_w;i++)
    matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(short)*mat_h); 
for (i=0;i<mat_w;i++)
    for (j=0;j<mat_h;j++)
        matrix[i][j]=0;
```

Comment: This is one case where I prefer the alternative use of `sizeof()` - `sizeof(matrix)` and `sizeof(*matrix)` would be much clearer here.

Comment: Also, for the love of Skeet, please check that `malloc()` didn't return `NULL`

Answer (score 15):

What compiler are you using that it doesn't scream at you about all these obvious errors?

`gcc -Wall` produced five warning messages with this code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    int mat_w = 99;
    int mat_h = 666;
    int i;
    int j;

    int **imatrix;
    short **smatrix;
    //mem allocation
    imatrix=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int*)*mat_w);
    for (i=0;i<mat_w;i++)
    imatrix[i]=(int)malloc(sizeof(int)*mat_h);
    //init
    for (i=0;i<mat_w;i++)
    for (j=0;j<mat_h;j++)
        imatrix[i][j]=0;

    //mem allocation
    smatrix=(short*)malloc(sizeof(short*)*mat_w);
    for (i=0;i<mat_w;i++)
    smatrix[i]=(short)malloc(sizeof(short)*mat_h);
    //init
    for (i=0;i<mat_w;i++)
    for (j=0;j<mat_h;j++)
        smatrix[i][j]=0;
    return 0;
}
```

Gives me

```
malloc.c: In function 'main':
malloc.c:13: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
malloc.c:15: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
malloc.c:22: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
malloc.c:24: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
malloc.c:24: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

Answer (score 6):

There's a serious lesson your have to learn from this mistake. And it says the following: ***never cast the result of 'malloc'***.

Moreover, this is a part of a bigger good-practice gudeline that is best followed whenever possible: ***never mention type names in your code, except in declarations***.

This is how your code should have looked from the very beginning

```
  int **matrix;

  matrix = malloc(mat_w * sizeof *matrix);
  for (i = 0; i < mat_w; i++)
    matrix[i] = malloc(mat_h * sizeof *matrix[i]);

  for (i = 0; i < mat_w; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < mat_h; j++)
      matrix[i][j] = 0;
```

Note, that in order to switch from 'int' to 'short' in this version you just need to change the declaration of 'matrix' and nothing else.

(Of course, there's more that can be improved in this code, but I just wanted to address the immediate reason for the error.)

Answer (score 5):

You are casting your `int**` to `int*` the return value of malloc (same for short). `malloc` should be use as this:

```
matrix = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * mat_w);
```

or

```
matrix = (short**)malloc(sizeof(short*) * mat_w);
```

Same for each allocation inside matrix:

```
matrix[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * mat_h);
```

or

```
matrix[i] = (short*)malloc(sizeof(short) * mat_h);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are doing something wrong.

```
 int *matrix;
```

means that `matrix` is an array of integers. If you want it to be an array of arrays of integers, you should declare it like this:

```
 int **matrix;
 //mem allocation
 matrix=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*mat_w);
 for (i=0; i<mat_w; i++)
     matrix[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*mat_h);
 //init
 for (i=0; i<mat_w; i++)
     for (j=0; j<mat_h; j++)
         matrix[i][j]=0;
```

Of course, if you know in advance the dimensions of the matrix, just do it like this:

```
int matrix[mat_w][mat_h];
 //init
 for (i=0; i<mat_w; i++)
     for (j=0; j<mat_h; j++)
         matrix[i][j]=0;
```

Comment: +1, a note about the second example, there the matrix is stored on stack, sometimes if the matrix is big enough, the compiler will refuse to create it on stack, and there will be a necessity to  allocate it on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(int)` equals to bus width of the particular system. You are trying to put 32bit(or 64 depending on your platform) address value to a 16bit allocated memory.

Check out second example in the Checkers post. This is the correct and preferable way of memory allocation.